# Mac OSX: Terminal command to replicate activity monitor network data?

Tags: networking, mac, command-line, display, terminal

I've been googling around for a while now to try and find a terminal command which can output total kb/s IN and OUT for wifi (en0).

The command cannot use sudo, so lsof is out.

I've tried using netstat with the -w option, but the command is going to be run by a script which auto-refreshes, so there's a conflict with using -w.

What I'm aiming to do is replicate the output of Activity Monitor's `data sent/sec`, but with a terminal command which can be repeated every second.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to monitor network traffic every second is with `netstat -w 1`, as you mentioned.

However, it seems like you want to have some other script which is called (?) every second and is perhaps parsing the output from netstat?

How about piping the output from netstat to a file, like `netstat -w 1 > /tmp/netstat_output.txt &`?  Run that once (or as a Launch Agent), and then just have your other script examine the output (maybe like `tail -1 /tmp/netstat_output.txt`).  If your script is really going to be repeated/called every second, there is the possibility that you'll read the same row twice (if the time delta between 2 runs of your script is shorter than the time delta of the netstat output).

Simplest option would be `netstat -w 1`, and just let netstat do the refreshing, though, and not have the calling script be repeated/refreshed.

Comment: Thanks @jimtut - that could be a solution. The reason I can't use netstat -w is that the program requires an output/result, rather than the "streamed" output of netstat -w.... It is a bit frustrating, but piping the output might work. The problem there would be a potentially huge file...!

Comment: What language is your program in?  It should be possible to pipe `netstat` directly into your program, instead of using a temp file.

Comment: Thanks @jimtut. To avoid beating around the bush, I'm trying to write a widget for Ubersicht (a new GeekTool alternative) to show total en0 In/Out KB/s (like iStat Menus). Here's the issue on Github (which shows code examples etc): https://github.com/felixhageloh/uebersicht-widgets/issues/8

Comment: I tried the `iftop` mentioned on Github, but that command doesn't terminate either (not that I can tell), and it's output would be even harder to parse than `netstat`.  There is a `-s` option mentioned when you run `iftop -h` (the help page), but it's not documented in the `man` page, and it doesn't seem to work.  Perhaps it's a feature they removed, or maybe it's something they're planning on adding?  If you like the `iftop` option you can contact the developers and ask about the `-s` option.  Note that `iftop` seems to require that you run it like `sudo iftop` which may not work in a widget.